# progress-bar при чтении текста

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

У меня есть такой вот недоскрипт прогресс бара, который движется, когда скроллиш вниз-вверх.

```
var o = $('body').scrollTop() / ($(document.getElementById('progress_bar')).height() - $(window).height());
            $(".progress-bar").css({
                "width": (100 * o | 0) + "%"
            });
            $('progress')[0].value =
```

но скрипт не совсем правильный. Так вот как сделать [как по ссылке](http://firstround.com/review/okrs-are-old-news-introducing-goal-science-thinking/?ct=t(How_Does_Your_Leadership_Team_Rate_12_3_2015)?

Comment: Попробуйте взять полную высоту документа, и отслеживайте $(window).scrollTop()., в зависимости от $(window).scrollTop() давайте ширину прогрес бару

Comment: Спасибо! Почти разобралась. Но нужно, чтобы  прогресс бар появлялся не с самого начало, а когда доходишь до определенного div c id="text". Ну или после того как с экрана скроется div c id='header_wrapper'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу подсказать только в какую сторону копать, вот так работает, но нужно кое что подправить.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
}
 

.nav{
 width: 100%;
 height: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background: white;
}

.nav-add{
 width: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 background: blue;
 transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.block{
 height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
  var h = $(document).height();

  $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
   var scrTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.nav-add').css('width', (scrTop * 100 / h)+'%' )

  });
 })
</script>

<body>


<div class="nav"><div class="nav-add"></div></div>

<div class="block block1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, corrupti, molestias? Esse, dicta. Fugiat laborum nobis porro aliquam dolores beatae, maxime quo similique dicta unde, qui in deserunt, reprehenderit nihil quod ratione mollitia magnam? Consequatur repellendus tenetur ab molestiae accusantium quas reprehenderit cum dolorem magnam, ratione distinctio nisi vel fugit provident! Distinctio praesentium neque fuga. Enim sunt, quo consequatur iste beatae odio. Id magni, a rem. Alias eveniet nam tempora totam, inventore quia eius reiciendis, fugiat excepturi! Debitis qui quaerat itaque deleniti facere nisi quis dolorem, quo voluptatibus dolore commodi excepturi praesentium consectetur at hic aut maiores distinctio alias assumenda.</div>
<div class="block block2">Debitis alias accusantium quae autem, dolore saepe porro corrupti quos sapiente a ipsum quia ad, totam necessitatibus sunt expedita? Tempore tenetur repudiandae corporis dicta iste enim, veniam odit veritatis, labore reprehenderit doloribus consequuntur quibusdam illum maiores voluptas qui animi quasi, obcaecati laborum quos numquam minima pariatur cumque possimus. Cumque sit cum impedit dolorem deserunt consequatur voluptatum numquam sapiente mollitia, esse omnis nulla, hic a. Id velit recusandae atque consequatur voluptates animi alias qui, dignissimos dolore nisi cupiditate doloremque maiores vero optio saepe illo nobis ipsa fuga labore, assumenda deleniti doloribus! Minima fugiat quasi incidunt ratione quia magni accusamus dolor consequuntur!</div>
<div class="block block3">Architecto ad quaerat dignissimos, ducimus incidunt officia, distinctio soluta tempora sit quae illo eveniet? Consequuntur nesciunt veniam culpa voluptate eius obcaecati, et, deleniti dicta rem molestias sit, iusto, distinctio architecto inventore id. Molestias dolorum hic corporis odit obcaecati sapiente facere amet. Neque vel praesentium a dicta esse, inventore nihil deserunt veniam nulla tenetur dolorem quibusdam fugiat! At similique aspernatur eos illum laborum molestiae dolores aperiam autem, perspiciatis tempore ut beatae quos mollitia, dignissimos maiores deleniti impedit nostrum enim adipisci quidem? Dicta temporibus quis molestias, possimus quia enim dolor nam eveniet animi perspiciatis unde nobis, id asperiores in quisquam, voluptas quidem!</div>
<div class="block block4">Eaque in et odio, veritatis consequatur voluptate id, voluptatem rerum molestias, maxime necessitatibus obcaecati explicabo ipsum. Vero quidem incidunt cum praesentium unde, accusamus exercitationem! Ullam sed inventore id distinctio sint ipsam labore temporibus molestiae, animi quo, dolore odit alias! Minus, tempora culpa doloremque. Magni eligendi deserunt nobis accusamus. Repudiandae laborum assumenda, et magnam earum totam. Ipsam rerum voluptatibus aliquam nisi ad eligendi doloribus unde sed cumque, sapiente ullam sunt fugit repellendus! Esse ullam, nostrum praesentium, non placeat sapiente rerum, recusandae vel magni illum tenetur at amet sunt fugiat similique distinctio mollitia dolorum soluta, voluptatibus unde modi earum harum. Odio, eos!</div>
<div class="block block5">Expedita odio similique ipsa perferendis aspernatur quidem, est sequi officia, obcaecati a. Culpa beatae nostrum accusamus quia nobis voluptatum ipsum nulla reprehenderit ratione optio ducimus, cupiditate porro, odit commodi obcaecati. Laborum incidunt voluptate odio voluptatibus deserunt laboriosam hic at praesentium animi quia modi ut veniam recusandae voluptatem ipsum quaerat sequi blanditiis eaque consequatur maiores debitis, harum cumque nostrum! Repellendus incidunt, praesentium quod adipisci facere placeat blanditiis pariatur, est consequuntur, reprehenderit reiciendis nostrum enim sunt porro! Totam placeat delectus eveniet repellat, nihil architecto molestias, distinctio aspernatur hic. Reprehenderit quisquam, nisi culpa cupiditate laboriosam ea iure, neque, omnis officiis voluptate dolorem dolorum.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: короче, тут математика 6 класса. `$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
            var scroll_line = ($(window).scrollTop() - header_height) / (elem_height - height_window);
            
            $(".progress-bar").css({
                "width": (100 * scroll_line) + "%"
            });
            $('progress')[0].value = scroll_line;
        })`

Comment: я как раз 6й класс пропустил)